# Publish from Intellij to an existing Github repository

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, egit

I have an existing repo on Github called General.
I have in my Intellij workspace two separate projects that I want to publish on Github, but I want them to go as subfolders inside the existing General repo.

How can I do it from Intellij? All I could find online was how to publish each one of my projects to a new Github repo. That would be a mess.

I was able to do it with the Eclipse Github plugin (EGit), but the Intellij support seems to have much less options.

Comment: You have to clone the repo, move the projects into the repo's directory, open the repo in intellij, add the (new) subfolders, and commit them.

Comment: Conceptually is it not turning these two separate projects into one project? That's problematic since they are not so related and also not in the same language. If I get it right, every Git repo represents a project. If I remember right, in Eclipse I was able to keep the two projects separate in the workspace and in the file system, but on Github they appear in one repo.